# Maya Python: Something is not defined (Building Generator)

Tags: python, undefined, global

I'm new to this site, and new to programming in general. I've been working on a procedural building generator in Maya2018 using Python as my language (Pycharm as my script editor).

1. I'm getting an error saying this: "Error: Global name 'WidthSections' is not defined."
2. I'm having an issue getting the width and height of my 'Window' model. I might have gone about this the wrong way, but I tried subtracting the xmax by the xmin to get the width, and the ymax by the ymin to get the height. Perhaps I'm not writing this in the correct spot. Any suggestions would be really helpful!

Code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def windowConstruction(numWindowsInwidth = 5, numWindowsInDepth = 3,numFloors = 5):
    #Creating Window Panel#
    w = 5
    h = 8
    sx = 5
    sy = 6

    bWindow = cmds.polyCube(w=w, h=h, sx=sx, sy=sy, n="window")
    cmds.polyExtrudeFacet("window.f[21]","window.f[22]","window.f[23]","window.f[16]","window.f[17]","window.f[18]","window.f[11]","window.f[12]","window.f[13]","window.f[6]","window.f[7]","window.f[8]", thickness=-0.2, offset=0.1)
    cmds.polyExtrudeFacet("window.f[75]", "window.f[74]","window.f[73]", "window.f[72]", "window.f[71]", "window.f[70]", "window.f[76]", "window.f[77]", "window.f[78]", "window.f[79]", "window.f[80]", "window.f[81]", thickness=1.5)
    cmds.polyExtrudeFacet("window.f[111]", "window.f[113]","window.f[115]", "window.f[117]", "window.f[119]", "window.f[121]", "window.f[109]", "window.f[106]", "window.f[104]", "window.f[102]", "window.f[100]", "window.f[98]", thickness=0.3)
    cmds.polyExtrudeFacet("window.f[0]","window.f[1]","window.f[2]","window.f[3]","window.f[4]", offset=0.2, thickness=0.4)
    cmds.polyExtrudeFacet("window.f[6]","window.f[7]","window.f[8]","window.f[11]","window.f[12]","window.f[13]","window.f[16]","window.f[17]","window.f[18]","window.f[21]","window.f[22]","window.f[23]", offset=0.1)
    cmds.polyExtrudeFacet("window.f[6]","window.f[7]","window.f[8]","window.f[11]","window.f[12]","window.f[13]","window.f[16]","window.f[17]","window.f[18]","window.f[21]","window.f[22]","window.f[23]", offset=0.1, thickness=-0.3)
    cmds.select("window.e[279]","window.e[274]","window.e[269]","window.e[264]","window.e[259]", "window.e[252]","window.e[246]","window.e[241]","window.e[236]","window.e[231]","window.e[226]", "window.e[219]")
    cmds.polyBevel("window.e[279]","window.e[274]","window.e[269]","window.e[264]","window.e[259]", "window.e[252]","window.e[246]","window.e[241]","window.e[236]","window.e[231]","window.e[226]", "window.e[219]")
    cmds.polyExtrudeFacet("window.f[110]", "window.f[126]", "window.f[30]", "window.f[31]", "window.f[32]", "window.f[33]","window.f[34]", "window.f[103]", "window.f[119]", "window.f[121]", "window.f[104]","window.f[65]", "window.f[66]", "window.f[67]", "window.f[68]", "window.f[69]", "window.f[96]", "window.f[112]", thickness=1.5)
    cmds.select("window.f[110]", "window.f[126]", "window.f[30]", "window.f[31]", "window.f[32]", "window.f[33]","window.f[34]", "window.f[103]", "window.f[119]", "window.f[121]", "window.f[104]","window.f[65]", "window.f[66]", "window.f[67]", "window.f[68]", "window.f[69]", "window.f[96]", "window.f[112]", d=True)
    cmds.move(h / 2.0 + 1.49, bWindow, moveY=True)
    cmds.move(w / 2.0 + 1.49, bWindow, moveX=True)
    cmds.move(8, 0, 0, bWindow[0]+".scalePivot", bWindow[0]+".rotatePivot", absolute=True)
    cmds.makeIdentity(bWindow, apply=True, translate=True, t=1, r=1, s=1, n=0)

    #Bounding Box of Windows#
    xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax = cmds.xform(bWindow, query=True, bb=True)

    #Duplication/Translation of Windows#
    numWindowsInwidth = 5
    numWindowsInDepth = 3
    numFloors = 5
    i = 1

    while i <= widthSections:
        sectionWidth = cmds.getAttr(bWindow, xmax-xmin)
        cmds.duplicate()
        cmds.move(-sectionWidth, 0, 0, relative=True)
        i += 1
    cmds.rotate(0, -90, 0, relative=True)



    while i <= depthSections:
        sectionWidth = cmds.getAttr(bWindow, xmax-xmin)
        cmds.duplicate()
        cmds.move(0, 0, -sectionWidth, relative=True)
        i += 1
    cmds.rotate(0, -90, 0, relative=True)



    while i <= widthSections:
        sectionWidth = cmds.getAttr(bWindow, xmax-xmin)
        cmds.duplicate()
        cmds.move(sectionWidth, 0, 0, relative=True)
        i += 1
    cmds.rotate(0, -90, 0, relative=True)



    while i < depthSections:
        sectionWidth = cmds.getAttr(bWindow, xmax-xmin)
        cmds.duplicate()
        cmds.move(0, 0, sectionWidth, relative=True)
        i += 1


    cmds.select('window*')
    while i < heightSections:
        sectionHeight = cmds.getAttr(bWindow, xmax-xmin)
        cmds.duplicate()
        cmds.move(0, sectionHeight, 0, relative=True)
        i += 1

    #Grouping All Windows#
    cmds.select('window*')
    cmds.group('window*', name="Windows")

windowConstruction()
```

Answer (score 1):

Precisely as the error message is saying, you have a variable `widthSection` that is used on the line `while i <= widthSections:` that is not defined. At some point in your code this variable needs to be given a value which is not happening. Similarly you'll likely find that `depthSections` will not be defined for the same reason

You have two unused variables `numWindowsInwidth` and `numWindowsInDepth`. I am guessing that these are the variable you should actually be using in that loop rather than the `widthSections` and `depthSections` you are currently using.

e.g.

```
while i <= numWindowsInwidth:
    sectionWidth = cmds.getAttr(bWindow, xmax-xmin)
    cmds.duplicate()
    cmds.move(-sectionWidth, 0, 0, relative=True)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks for your post! I'll give it a try right now.